# Actualizar password Hash

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, hash

Estoy tratando de encontrar una sentencia SQL para actualizar el password de la base de datos de mi CMS, por lo cual necesito que el `update` sea `password_hash` y como resultado me muestre el nuevo password en hash con las primeras iniciales **$2y$10$**

Pruebo lo siguiente en phpmyadmin, lo cual esta mal:

```
 UPDATE users SET password = password_hash('newpass') WHERE id = 000;
```

Comment: Y el algoritmo de hashing de SQL es el mismo que utiliza tu CMS?

Comment: @BaruchSpinoza cómo puedo saberlo?

Comment: Navegando en la documentación de MySQL y de tu CMS, por ejemplo para MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy improbable que tu CMS y MySQL usen el mismo algoritmo para encriptar contraseñas.

Por ende, sólo deberías usar uno de los dos métodos.

Por ejemplo, si MySQl usa SHA256 para encriptar las contraseñas, pero tu CMS usa bcrypt, no resultará el mismo hash a partir de la misma contraseña.

Los CMS más populares ya vienen con métodos para resetear contraseñas.